# How to fix a bcache partition where the pyhsical size is less than the superblock size

Tags: partitioning, disk, bcache

I'm in the process of migrating data to a bcache partition. I've created the backing disk and cache disk, and I used dd to copy data from another partition (of the same size) to the new `/dev/bcache0` partition.

Unfortunately, it appears that even though the backing partition `/dev/sdb1` is the same size as the source partition, the actual bcache partition `/dev/bcache0` is slightly smaller, and the dd operation failed.

Checking the disk reveals the difference between the physical and superblock sizes of `/dev/bcache0`:

```
# fsck /dev/bcache0
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 122086400 blocks
The physical size of the device is 122086998 blocks
```

I've been able to increase the size of `/dev/sdb1` using parted, however I'm reluctant to do the same with `/dev/bcache0` without knowing the implications, and without calculating the new size very carefully.

What's my best course of action from here to get the `/dev/bcache0` partition mountable?

There shouldn't have been any data at the end of the source disk, so I'm assuming the data on `/dev/bcache0` is intact, but inaccessible due to the partition misconfiguration. Unfortunately I also accidentally deleted the data from the source disk, so I can't migrate it a second time. I have a working backup of all the critical data, but I'd rather see if I can recover the bcache partition before resorting to that.